# Change layout based on url parameter - Magento 2.4

Tags: module, layout, event-observer

We created a custom module, to load a observer before layout_load_before. And then we would like to change the custom layout, based on a url parameter `?content-only=yes`. For some reason it does not work, what are we missing here?

Code:

```
App/Code/Module/ModuleName/Observer/AddUpdateHandlesObserver.php


<?php
namespace Module\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

/**
 * Class AddUpdateHandlesObserver
 * @package Test\Module\Observer
 */
class AddUpdateHandlesObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @var Http
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;


/**
 * AddUpdateHandlesObserver constructor.
 * @param Http                       $request           Request
 * @param StoreManagerInterface      $storeManager      StoreManager
 * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository ProductRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    Http $request,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->request           = $request;
    $this->storeManager      = $storeManager;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}


/**
 * @param Observer $observer Observer
 * @return $this|bool|void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $layout  = $observer->getData('layout');
    $request = $this->request;

    if ($request->getParam('content-only')=='yes') {
        $block = $layout->getBlock('header-wrapper'); $layout->unsetElement('header-wrapper');
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('layout_file_name');
    }

    return $this;
}

}
```

The events.xml

```
App/Code/Module/ModuleName/etc/frontend/event.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="test_layout_change" instance="Module\Module\Observer\AddUpdateHandlesObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating separate pages for each use case as changing layout in observer that is run on server side doesn't work when there is cache involved. The observer would not run for cached pages as the request doesn't reach server and the server would instead serve the page that is in cache.

Although, if you are serving different page layout to different customer groups this should work as Magento's cache is segmented based on customer group.

**EDIT**

Another way of going about this is managing the page at client side. For eg. if you would like to remove the head/header/footer of a specific page when using a parameter, then you could apply a css to the page so that by default the page doesn't show the unecessary elements, on page load or during the page load when the elements in question are rendered you would check the parameter using jQuery and then show the elements.

Yet another way of doing it would be Edge Side Includes (ESI). You can read up of this here - https://alankent.me/2014/12/09/magento-2-caching-overview/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly we can not create separate pages easily, because we want to load only the content of a already existing page. We would like to remove the head/header/footer of a specific page when using this parameter. This so we can load this content on another page using jQuery load function.

Comment: Please check the edit